# Error while using parse.com as notification server

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform

In my app I use parse.com to receive push notification from a remote service. I followed the tutorial direct on parse.com site and the apps receive correctly the notification, but when I start the app from Xcode I see that the app calls the method: `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` and Xcode shows me the following:

```
Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 3000 "no permission string 'aps-environment' found valid for the application" UserInfo = {0x1567fa20 NSLocalizedDescription = no permission string 'aps-environment' found valid for the application}
```

and I see that the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` is not called so I can't get the InstallationId I've to send to the server to listen to the channel of push notification.

What's wrong in my app? I'm running it on a real device and it works fine when I try to send a notification through the website, can anyone help me to understand what's wrong? I followed the tutorial to create a certificate to make work with push notification.
On my Apple account I got a few of certificate to develop app without the push notification and I use a wildcard like this: `it.name.*`. I created a certificate for push notification with this appID: `it.name.app`, I guess it's not this one the issue.
Thank you for helping

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your provisioning profiles. Search SO for solutions

Comment: @lucgian841 post your answer and mark it like the correct one please.

Comment: @FabioCardoso I wrote my answer below but I can accept it in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked on project settings and I just solved the issue with certificate by adding a developer team. Now my app call the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` and I get the InstallationId to send to my server. I hope someone will use my solution.